# C# Threading error + Backgroundworker component

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am getting an error which says object reference not set to instance of an object when I try to update UI element via dispatcher.

The sample code is ->

```
backgroundworker.DoWork += >
{
// do some work here.

// close the progressbar over here

    _progressBar.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                                            new Action( _progressBar.Close);
}
```

I get an error Object reference not set in the _progressBar.Dispatcher.Invoke statement and my application totally hangs.

Comment: "_progressBar.Close" should be passed without brackets (if that is the name of the method you try to invoke).

Comment: Its a typo over here.. I have corrected the same !

Comment: How `_progressBar` is defined and set? It seems that the `_progressBar` is null.

Comment: The progress bar is a class level member variable, and when I debug I can see in the quick watch window, that it points to a instance, it points to a instance :)- . after calling Dowork on background worker thread I do a progress bar .showdialog..

Comment: Clearly it is not an UI element or a ProgressBar, it must be a Window to have a Close() method.  You would not write code like this in DoWork, it belongs in a RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Comment: @Sandepku And what is actually done in DoWork? Are you reporting progress there via progress bar, or closing progress bar when work is done?

Comment: I am loading a 45MB excel file in the doWork.. .. @Hans Passant, I agree, I will try moving the code over there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the value of `_progressBar` is not null? Maybe it is `null` at a different point in time.

I would add following lines to check for it:

```
new Action(() => {
                    if (_progressBar == null){
                        if (Debugger.IsAttached){
                            Debugger.Break();
                        } else {
                            Debug.Fail("_progressbar is null!");
                        }
                     } else {
                       _progressBar.Close();
                     }
                  });
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried this approach, and also moved the code to runCompleted. It helped a lot thanks...